# Java EE web application does not deploy on JBoss

Tags: eclipse, oracle, jpa, jboss

I work on a Java EE web application, I use Eclipse Indigo as IDE, JBoss 7.1 as application server and Oracle 10j as Database.
I created this directory `modules\oracle\jdbc\driver\main` in the home folder of JBoss 7.1 and I add the Oracle driver and the file `module.xml`.
The contents of the `module.xml` file is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="oracle.jdbc.driver">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

I've done all the necessary configuration on the file server `standalone.xml`.
The contents of the `standalone.xml` file is as follows:

```xml
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/EmnaDS" pool-name="11gDS" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE</connection-url>
        <driver>oracle</driver>
        <pool>
            <prefill>false</prefill>
            <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
            <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>bct</user-name>
            <password>emna</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="oracle" module="oracle.jdbc.driver">
        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
        </driver>
        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

I created an EJB project in eclipse, I add the JPA facet.
The contents of the `persistence.xml` file is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="BCTProjet">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/EmnaDS</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.bct.entity.utilisateur</class>

    <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I add the project on the server and I run it, I have this result:

```
14:17:58,198 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/EmnaDS]
14:17:58,267 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.0.Final "Thunder" started in 9404ms - Started 135 of 206 services (70 services are passive or on-demand)
```

But the project is not deployed on the server and I could not see generated tables for the classes in the database?

Answer (score 0):

The log is too few to identify the problem. But your datasource is ok. I think something is wrong with your app. Or it doesn't deploy at all.

Comment: I can not deploy the project to the server, but no error is generated

Comment: That means the deployment is not triggered. are your file suffix is ear or war? did you put it into the right dir? Normally if you deploy as standalone, it should under C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments